# Alerting the user (Tracking) when call gets connected - Win8 metro style

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have just started using **Win 8 Metro style Apps** development.

Is there a way exist to track when the out going call is connected?

I want to **alert the user (may be phone vibration), once connection is established**.

Please give me some hint to accomplish the same. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't heard of any phones running Windows 8, so you're talking nonsense.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen : I agree that it has not been launched. But is it bad to be prepared with the Apps & that would be useful in near future? Win 8 phone is almost ready to launch, may be in next 3 to 4 months max...

Comment: No, Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 is two completely different operative systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about simple phone calls, then no.  All call-related activity is handled by the system, and your app has no control over it and therefore no need to be notified about it.    If you initiate a call task from your app, the app is put into the background, and the system takes over to handle the call.  This is the same behaviour as in previous Windows Phone versions.